# Properly override inline field sets in custom admin template

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

I have customized template for one of my app. This template extends `admin/change_form.html`.

Model has few inlines. And I need to locate each inline form on different tabs.

So this is how I have done:

```
{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}">{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>
{% endfor %}

{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading vertical-tab-accordion-heading" rel="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}">{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>
   <div id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
        {{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}
        {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
{% block inline_field_sets %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that it saves only one record in inline forms.
But if i will remove my custom for loop block, and just leave it as default everything works fine!

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was the problem.
This line of code is redundant:

`{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}`